# list index out of range using get()

Tags: python

I got an error of `'list' object has no attribute 'get'`. Usually, it worked fine,

```
weather_1D_ago = data['city']['weather']['daily'][0]['actual']['fmt']
weather_2D_ago = data['city']['weather']['daily'][1]['actual']['fmt']

'city': {'weather': {'daily': [{'actual': {'fmt': '1.2',
                                           'raw': 1.2},
                                'date': '1D_ago',
                                'estimate': {'fmt': '1.3',
                                             'raw': 1.3}},
                               {'actual': {'fmt': '2.2',
                                           'raw': 2.2},
                                'date': '2D_ago',
                                'estimate': {'fmt': '2.3',
                                             'raw': 2.3}},,
```

Until the path was missing, as shown below:

```
'city': {'weather': {'daily': []},
```

**Update:** I tried to use `.get()` to achieve the data, and make it return as `None` if the value is missing.

```
weather_1D_ago = data['city']['weather'].get('daily', {})[0].get('actual', {}).get('fmt', {})
weather_2D_ago = data['city']['weather'].get('daily', {})[1].get('actual', {}).get('fmt', {})
```

But I just got an error of `list index out of range`

I'd avoid using `try-except` blocks because it will mix up my other codes when referred to `weather_1D_ago` and another error will generate: `local variable 'weather_1D_ago' referenced before assignment`

So, how would you make it return `None` using `.get()` even if the path is not valid? Thanks!

Comment: `print(type(<your object here>))` if its a `list`. You can't use `get()` and must use indexing like `[0]`. If its a `dict`, you can use `get()`. Note that if a `list index out of range (IndexError)` happens on `[0]`, then the list is empty.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right. I just edited it.

Comment: @JacobIRR yes it's a list, but how would you return it to be `None` if the list is empty as I'm using for loop to process the data? Maybe I should edit my question a bit.

Comment: `your_list or None` will return `None` if the list is empty

Comment: @JacobIRR It returned an error: `list index out of range`. Is it because there's no `['daily'][1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def safe_list_get(l, i):
    if l and i < len(l):
        return l[i]
    return {}

weather_1D_ago = safe_list_get(data['city']['weather'].get('daily', []),0).get('actual', {}).get('fmt', {})
weather_2D_ago = safe_list_get(data['city']['weather'].get('daily', []),1).get('actual', {}).get('fmt', {})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Could you tell me why would you put `return l[i]` in `try`?

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate `if l and i < len(l): return l[i]`? I don't really get it. Appreciated

Comment: If the list is not None or empty and i is less than the length of list then list[i] will be returned. In all other cases default value of {} will be returned.

Comment: Ohhhh! Got it! Thanks!!